# How to use document write inside a url with double quote

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to put a variable using script on an image url but it does not seem to work instead the url display the encoded text

```
<img src="<script type="text/javascript">document.write(image_one);</script>"
```

Comment: @ThisClark — They did

Comment: There are better ways to do this and not use document.write

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

You can't put an element inside an attribute value.

You can either generate the entire element from JavaScript, or you can create it with a default value for the `src` and then use DOM to change the `src` to something else.